# \setotherlanguage{hebrew} messing with footnotes

Tags: footnotes, hebrew

I have changed the original post so as to fix my own mistakes with the MWE. Also I discovered that \setotherlanguage{hebrew} is the real culprit, not setspace.sty.

\setotherlanguage{hebrew} is causing my footnote text to be doublespaced, when I need it single spaced.

Thanks for your patience.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin={1in},vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[backend=biber,footmarkoff]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{diss.bib}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\doublespacing


\begin{document}
\chapter{Palaeographical Profile}

\section*{Introduction}

Some text here and there

\section*{Style of the Hand}
Text of various kinds.\footnote{this is a footnote that should be single space per the style guide I am following in my school. Please help. And thank you very much. Just trying to make the footnote long enough. That's all. Don't mind me.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I try your example it stops with the error `! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \setmainlanguage` please test that the example demonstrates the issue that you are asking about.

Comment: if I comment out the undefined commands `\setmainlanguage` and `\setmainfont` the example runs but has a single spaced footnote text

Comment: IIRC one of the selling points of `setspace` is that it (by default) does not change the footnote spacing. And indeed if I add `\usepackage{polyglossia}` (before `biblatex`) to your example to make it compilable the footnote text is single-spaced. Please double check if the example really reproduces the issue for you (and if not, amend the example so that it does).

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to initialize the languages *before* changing anything else.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin={1in},vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\usepackage[backend=biber,footmarkoff]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{diss.bib}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\doublespacing


\begin{document}
\chapter{Palaeographical Profile}

\section*{Introduction}

Some text here and there

\section*{Style of the Hand}
Text of various kinds.\footnote{this is a footnote that should be single space per the style guide I am following in my school. Please help. And thank you very much. Just trying to make the footnote long enough. That's all. Don't mind me.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering!